# Get methods of class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to get list of methods defined for a class in js?

```js
class c {
  methodA(){}
  static methodB(){}

  log(){console.log(/*methods*/);}
  static logStatic(){console.log(/*static methods*/)}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)  and filter the `instance` and `static` methods:

```js
class c {
  methodA(){}
  static methodB(){}

  log(){console.log(/*methods*/);}
  static logStatic(){console.log(/*static methods*/)}
}
const instanceOnly = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c.prototype)
    .filter(prop => prop != "constructor");
console.log(instanceOnly);
const staticOnly = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(c)
    .filter(prop => typeof c[prop] === "function");
console.log(staticOnly);
```

Comment: Great!! thx ;))